# Call javascript function in Objective-C with JavaScriptCore

Tags: objective-c, javascriptcore

I have a javascript code (from [annevk/webvtt](https://github.com/annevk/webvtt)):

```js
var WebVTTParser = function () {
    this.parse = function (input, mode) {
        ...
    }
};
```

and in HTML I call it like this:

```js
var pa = new WebVTTParser()
var r = pa.parse(input, mode)
```

Now I want to evaluate this in Objective-C. I tried:

```
[jsContext evaluateScript:script];

JSValue *parse = jsContext[@"WebVTTParser"][@"parse"];
NSLog("%@", [parse toString]); // undefined

JSValue *parsed = [parse callWithArguments:@[ input, mode ]];
NSLog("%@", [parsed toString]); // undefined
```

without successful. `parse` is undefined, therefore `parsed` is undefined too.

If I use this:

```
JSValue *webVTTParser = jsContext[@"WebVTTParser"];
NSLog("%@", [webVTTParser toString]);

JSValue *parse = webVTTParser[@"parse"];
NSLog("%@", [parse toString]); // undefined
```

or this:

```
JSValue *webVTTParser = jsContext[@"WebVTTParser"];
NSLog("%@", [webVTTParser toString]);

JSValue *parserFunction = [webVTTParser callWithArguments:@[]]; // equivalent new WebVTTParser()?
NSLog(@"%@", [parserFunction toString]); // undefined

JSValue *parse = parserFunction[@"parse"];
NSLog("%@", [parse toString]); // undefined
```

then `webVTTParser` is printed out in console log, but everything else is still undefined so I can't run it.

How can I access `this.parse` function from `webVttParser`?

Answer (score 0):

Okay after reading source code of [`JSValue`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore-7601.1.46.3/API/JSValue.h), I found the solution for this.

`new WebVTTParser()` will be

```js
JSValue *webVTTParser = jsContext[@"WebVTTParser"];
JSValue *parser = [webVTTParser constructWithArguments:@[]];
```

from Apple:

```
/*!
@method
@abstract Invoke a JSValue as a constructor.
@discussion This is equivalent to using the <code>new</code> syntax in JavaScript.
@param arguments The arguments to pass to the constructor.
@result The return value of the constructor call.
*/
- (JSValue *)constructWithArguments:(NSArray *)arguments;
```

and to access `this.parse` method:

```js
JSValue *parsed = [parser invokeMethod:@"parse" withArguments:@[ input, mode ]];
```

as in:

```
/*!
@method
@abstract Invoke a method on a JSValue.
@discussion Accesses the property named <code>method</code> from this value and
            calls the resulting value as a function, passing this JSValue as the
            <code>this</code> value along with the specified arguments.
@param method The name of the method to be invoked.
@param arguments The arguments to pass to the method.
@result The return value of the method call.
*/
- (JSValue *)invokeMethod:(NSString *)method withArguments:(NSArray *)arguments;
```

But because I have to construct and call several methods, so instead of those complicated Objective-C codes, I add my own javascript function in the script:

```js
var parse = function(input, mode) {
    var pa = new WebVTTParser(),
        r = pa.parse(input, mode);
    ...
    return ...
};
```

and call only this function in Obj-C.